# Creating an AsyncTask to use with an AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, alarmmanager, android-wifi

Since I just want to connect to a web service, in order to check whether there is an update or not, or to check whether there is a need to send data to that service, I believe AsyncTask and AlarmManager is perfect for this, but I don't know what to do about the Internet connection availability of the user.

Basicly, I think after reaching the time interval I'll constantly check for an internet connection, if available connect to that web service, and after the connections restart the AlarmManager for the next time. What I am missing is the constantly checking internet availability, and using AlarmManager properly for this. Any advice would be great for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for internet availability by creating a separate `thread with infinite loop`..you can implement this thread in `service`...

for alarm manager refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: I am an admitted noob, but this sounds like a bad idea to me. What happens if the user goes to airplane mode?  Your infinite loop just sucks up system resources. Why not use an inexact repeating alarm instead?

Comment: that's one way if alarm manager is serving your purpose then you should use that...which ever best suits your app ...use that one..

Comment: @Mobius can you explain the inexact repeating alarm?